# getting params from environment variables

Tags: python, environment-variables

I want to read the new environment variable from my script. I'm trying to export this var through ssh. I've tried

```
test = "qwerty"
cmd = "export my_password=%s;python script.py" % test
```

execute this command by ssh. In the script:

```
if os.environ.has_key("my_password"): print "ok"
else: print "failed"
```

I got "failed" as result. How should i set this env variable?

Comment: *How* do your execute this command by ssh, though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add it before the command without exporting it:

```
cmd = "my_password=%s python script.py" % test
```

Comment: Ahh, that's what it is.  I just accepted the invitation to that about 5 minutes ago ... I must confess that I didn't look at it very closely.  I saw "I love hats" and I was in immediately.